# Elasticsearch: score in percentage, with multi_match (fuzziness enabled) and filter in the same query, based in the multi_match part only

Tags: elasticsearch

Considering the Elasticsearch query below, I was wondering if it is possible to have the score in percentage (0-100%), or how could I calculate it in such way, and have it only based on the multi_match part of the query, where fuzziness is enabled.

Therefore, I would like the score to ignore the filter part of it.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "index": "myindex",
  "type": "mytype",
  "body": {
    "_source": [
      "author_mt",
      ...
      "title_t",
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [
              "title*"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "genre_t_s": 'test'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The elasticsearch score is based on the TF/IDF algorithm, therefore the score can be grater than 1(or 100%). Check the following link what is relevance:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html

Comment: this is a correct comment, but it is not an answer!